# Compare hashes in c

Tags: c, hash, sha256

I am trying to compare and match hashes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sha256.h"

int main()
{
   unsigned char password[]={"abc"}, gen_hash[32];
   SHA256_CTX ctx;

   sha256_init(&ctx);
   sha256_update(&ctx,password,strlen(password));
   sha256_final(&ctx,gen_hash);

   unsigned char orig_hash[] = {"ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad"};

   if(strcmp(orig_hash, gen_hash) == 0)
   {
    printf("%s\n", "match");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But If I compare both hashes, they are not the same. Does anyone happen to know why? I thought both the variables are the same, but are they not?

Comment: Recommend dropping the C++ tag, Err,... never mind

Comment: I would say the `orig_hash` is way longer than 32 chars...

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `gen_hash` is a null-terminated string and thus usable with `strcmp`

Comment: YOU COMPARE CHARACTERS VS. UNSIGNED NUMBERS OF 8 BITS... THEY DON'T HAVE THE SAME VALUE, THEY JUST LOOK THE SAME

Comment: @user4581301 The code does not even compile as C++, in cases that obvious, just edit it out.

Comment: I hadn't even looked that far when I commented. The title explicitly called out C.

Comment: @AlexLop. Wow, so what could I do now?

Comment: @Sam Look at my answer. That should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points:

1. Don't use `strcmp` but rather `memcmp` since the generated hash `gen_hash` won't have '\0' at the end.
2. You defined `orig_hash` as

   `unsigned char orig_hash[] = 
   {"ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad"};`

which is a string of characters. You should define it as a array of numbers:

```
unsigned char orig_hash[] = {0xba, 0x78, 0x16, 0xbf, ...};
```

Comment: is it possible to cast the `orig_hash` into this numbers?

Comment: Cast, no. that would result in a much larger array. Each hex digit is 4 bits, and when represented as a character the digit will be, most likely, 8 bits. You'll have to do this the hard way.

Comment: @Sam No. You need to initialize it with the values just like did it with the string... Just add `0x` to each pair of hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: @AlexLop. I see :D. But is there no generic solution, except adding `0x` by hand?